# Can Firebase MLkit be used without enabling billing in developers console?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to run the quickstart app for MLKit :https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit. I have already followed all the steps in firebase console to add the application but I get this error when using this demo application:

> E/ImageAnnotatorTask: batchAnnotateImages call failed with error: {"code":403,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"This API method requires billing to be enabled. Please enable billing on project #xxxxx by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/billing/enable?project=xxxx then retry.

It seems billing has to be enabled. LivePreviewActivity is working fine but StillImageActivity gives this error.

Comment: Yes. Firebase's ML Kit can be used without billing. I have used it underneath the free spark plan. I'm not completely sure, since I did this a while ago, but I think that nevertheless, you will have to choose the free pricing plan called Spark. Maybe it'll work after you choose that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the plan in the firebase console and it is currently on spark plan.

Comment: Oh, got it. It seems cloud vision APIs is not supported in MLKit spark free plan.

Comment: Yeah. The cloud vision APIs are not supported on the free plan, but you can still run the processes on the device, its just that it will have fewer features.

Comment: So, document text detection will not work?

Comment: It will work. By the way @sk_353, if you are interested in making an Android app for analyzing facial emotions like the quickstart app you were trying out, I have a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ishaanjav/Face_Analyzer) called [Face Analyzer](https://github.com/ishaanjav/Face_Analyzer) that, as the name suggests, analyzes faces. You can take a look at the [README here](https://github.com/ishaanjav/Face_Analyzer/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Essentially, it uses the Microsoft Face API to not only detect individual faces in an image, but also provide information about facial attributes for each face such as emotions, estimated age, gender, and more. All the information and steps about getting the free trial, API Key, and more are in the README. I just thought you'd be interested in checking it out.

Comment: I was actually looking for text extraction from images of books/documents. Your project looks very interesting as well. Will have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186863/discussion-between-ishaan-javali-and-sk-353).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Firebase's ML Kit can be used without billing. I have used it underneath the free Spark plan. If you are getting the error above, there are two things that you should check for.

- You should be under the Spark pricing plan. This is a free, $0 per month, plan
- Secondly, for Firebase's Spark plan, the Cloud APIs are not available. In order to use the Cloud APIs, you **have to** upgrade to at least the Blaze plan. Otherwise, you will have to stick to the on-device API.

*The image below shows an example of the different APIs for recognizing text in images and what features they provide.*

[image]
**Essentially, all of the ML Kit's features will work and you have access to them for free -  *(like Face Detection, Barcode Scanning, and Extracting Text From Images)* - but you will have to use the on-device API with your Spark plan unless you are fine with upgrading to use the Cloud APIs.**